# Array from Requests

Tags: php, arrays, get

Hi I've set up 2 scripts, both communicating back and forth.

One thing I'd like is for one script to post an unknown amount of GETs to the other script.

I'd like the other script to some how be able to grab all the GETS and put the values in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_GET already is an array. No reason you can't just copy it into your another array whose name is easier to type.

```
$array = $_GET;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to make GET requests from one script to another, put something like

```
file_get_contents( "http://www.yoursite.com/script_2.php?some_var=some_value" );
```

And then, in script_2.php just read the variable

```
$_GET['some_var'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to post your some GET data received by script_1.php from script_1.php to script_2.php,right?If so ,this probably can help you

```
<?php
/*@file script_1.php*/
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'url_of_script_2.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_GET);
curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

And in script_2.php,you will get the GET datas  by using `$_POST`.See [curl in manual](http://cn.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)